# NSString Variable Value disappearing after reassignment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Something strange is going on. When I reassign an NSString to my subString variable near the bottom of my code. It seems that the value of subString is empty in the output. I don't know if objectAtIndex is returning something weird or it's a memory problem. If I create a new variable instead of reassigning the value of subString, I can print see the correct value in the output console. If anyone could help me figure this out. It'd be greatly appreciated.

```
NSString *subString = @"";
if ([text length] > 0) 
{
    UITextRange *selectedRange = [_textView selectedTextRange];
    UITextPosition *cursorPosition = [_textView positionFromPosition:selectedRange.start offset:0];
    UITextRange *subTextRange = [_textView textRangeFromPosition:_textView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:cursorPosition];
    subString = [textView textInRange:subTextRange];
}

NSLog(subString);
NSLog(@" %s", [subString hasSuffix:@" "] ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
BOOL hasSpaceSuffix = [subString hasSuffix:@" "];
NSLog(@" %s", _taggingInProgress ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
NSArray *substringArray = [[subString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] retain];
if ([substringArray count] > 1) {
    int index = [substringArray count];
    if ([[substringArray objectAtIndex:index-1] isEqualToString:@" "])
    {
        NSLog(@"1st");
        subString = [substringArray objectAtIndex:index-2];
        NSLog(subString);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"2nd");
        subString = [substringArray objectAtIndex:index-1];
        NSLog(subString);
    }
    NSLog(@"AFTER");
    NSLog(subString);
}
```

Comment: Try using `retain` in both assignments and see if the value gets held. E.G. `subString = [[substringArray objectAtIndex:index-2]retain];`

Comment: could you post the output you get? 1st/2nd/AFTER?

Comment: @Cake: Obviously not since the code includes `retain`, which is illegal in ARC.

Comment: no ARC, I wanted to actually learn how to do this but seems like I'm not getting it entirely.

Comment: Maybe the array does not contain any NSStrings.

Comment: 2012-06-28 12:39:24.038 FreeFrom[18157:f803] @dfkj 

2012-06-28 12:39:24.039 FreeFrom[18157:f803]  TRUE

2012-06-28 12:39:24.040 FreeFrom[18157:f803]  TRUE

2012-06-28 12:39:24.040 FreeFrom[18157:f803] 2nd

2012-06-28 12:39:24.041 FreeFrom[18157:f803] AFTER

2012-06-28 12:39:24.041 FreeFrom[18157:f803] ENTERING TAG END

Comment: Try adding this trace `NSLog(@"STRING ARRAY: %@", [substringArray description]);` after initializing substringArray and report its output, please...

Comment: Wow thanks so much for the help guys it turns out it's a mistake on my part. Thx sergio for telling me to use that NSLog

Comment: Instead of typing NSLog... can you add more descriptions to the NSLog? Like NSLog("If text.length > 0. The value of subString is : ", subString). Your output is so difficult to read. Also try putting your output in the question and format it.

Comment: Just a tip: Never pass a string variable right into NSLog. At the minimum, you'll want to do `NSLog(@"%@", substring)`. The first argument to NSLog is a format string, which means it's treated specially, so it can lead to unexpected results if you pass an arbitrary string.

Comment: understood. FYI I was getting this error because I didn't properly anticipate the output of componentsSeperatedByString. Which for a string "aaa bbb ccc " with separator @" " is {@"aaa", @"bbb", @"ccc", ""}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use:

```
subString = [NSString stringWithString:[substringArray objectAtIndex:index]];
```

...fixed...